# Data scaling before call SMOTENC for continuos and categorical features

Tags: python, smote

so far my code is the following to run SMOTENC.

```py
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTENC
smt = SMOTENC(random_state=seed, categorical_features=[10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53], ratio=1.0, n_jobs = -1)     
# n_jobs = The number of threads to open if possible. ``-1`` means using all processors.
# default K=5 
X_res, y_res = smt.fit_sample(X_tra, y_tra)
```

The problem here is I was reading about SMOTE and, as it use KNN algorithm with euclidean distance, data should be scaled before to call `SMOTENC()`.

If the dataset has the first 10 features as integer and the rest as categorical ones, how should I do the scaling process in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to scale numerical/continuous features either using `MinMaxScaler` or `StandardScaler` depending on the distribution of your data. 
Regarding categorical features, isn't that the point of choosing `SMOTENC` over `SMOTE` algorithm?